# What are MDLA and MDMA?

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission

I'm looking at stuff for my 2001 Honda CR-V on Amazon.com, and it has a filter for transmission type. There are two options for automatic: `MDLA` and `MDMA`. I have searched on Google, and found the Minnesota Dental Lawyers Association and ecstasy. Searching for both terms at once brings up a bunch of spam-the-hell-out-of-search-keyword shopping sites, but no explanations. I'm pretty sure my vehicle has no desire to either sue any dentists or get high. Please explain these terms to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the answer provided by @MoveMoreCommentsLinkToTop.

It seems the distinction between MDLA and MDMA is Front Wheel Drive (FWD) and Four Wheel Drive 4WD. Internally the two seem to be exactly the same.

You can find the transmission model and serial number stamped on the transmission itself.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It's the number Honda assigns to the transmission. Sort of like a model number. Honda must have put two different transmissions in that year. GM would list it on an option service tag in the car but I don't know what Honda does. The dealer may be able to look it up by VIN number and tell you which transmission you have.

[List of Honda transmissions on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Honda_transmissions)

Someone is asking a similar question on the [honda-tech.com website](http://honda-tech.com/showthread.php?t=3040619) you might want to try asking there.

Comment: I looked through the manual, dealer's sticker (surprised it was still in the glove box after 6 years), the stickers under the door, the VIN plate, and no mention anywhere of transmission type. I'd rather not have to take it to a shop, and the dealer is a five hour drive from where I live now (not sure if they're even the original; it was bought used) :)

Comment: @Gordon You shouldn't have to take it to the dealer. Call the Parts Department and ask them if they can look it up by VIN number.